# Inserting Large Array Via Google Sheets API (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, google-sheets-api

I have a program that builds a large array. For this example, let's say it has 1 row. Then 78 columns. Here is a `print_r` of it:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => BIZ ID [1] => B1 - A3 - Butt Seat Cushion [2] => BSC - Test 1 - Interests - Testing - Top 5, EU - WC [3] => Test 1 - Old age (24M) - Top 5, EU - [£19.54 / 1.593 BEP] - WC – Copy [4] => Video 2 - Thumbnail 1 [5] => [6] => CONVERSIONS [7] => 2689 [8] => 1960 [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => 23.64 [20] => 157.59 [21] => 472.53 [22] => 92.87 [23] => 36.7255 [24] => 3.928511 [25] => 8.791372 [26] => 3.049461 [27] => 0.288293 [28] => 2.119747 [29] => 0.414737 [30] => 0.4925 [31] => 0.347647 [32] => 3.94 [33] => 2.149091 [34] => 7.88 [35] => 923 [36] => 446 [37] => 225 [38] => 117 [39] => 87 [40] => 78 [41] => 5 [42] => [43] => 48 [44] => 68 [45] => 6 [46] => 11 [47] => [48] => ABOVE_AVERAGE [49] => BELOW_AVERAGE_20 [50] => AVERAGE [51] => [52] => 1.371939 [53] => 3.214286 [54] => 0.375238 [55] => 2.44898 [56] => 48 [57] => 0.591 [58] => 0.606154 [59] => 4.728 [60] => 4.728 [61] => 7.88 [62] => 40 [63] => 39 [64] => 5 [65] => 5 [66] => 3 [67] => 993 [68] => 993 [69] => 6 [70] => [71] => 4 [72] => NAME [73] => 307978786963089 [74] => 23845484873330137 [75] => 23845818516690137 [76] => 23845818516750137 [77] => 2020-10-16 [78] => 2020-11-14 ) )
```

I would like to insert this into a Google Sheet. I have been able to do this with a simple array. However, I'm having trouble with this large array. I have got this code working fine:

```
// Initilize client
$this->client = new \Google_Client();
$this->client->setApplicationName('My PHP App');
$this->client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
$this->client->setAccessType('offline');
$this->client->setAuthConfig("$authJSONFile");

// Initilize sheet
$this->sheets = new \Google_Service_Sheets($this->client);

// Sheet ID
$this->sheetID = $sheetID;

$values = [["1", "2"],["3", "4"]];

$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([

  'values' => $values 

]);

$params = [

  'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'

];

$update_sheet = $this->sheets->spreadsheets_values->update($this->sheetID, ""Sheet1!A1:B2"", $body, $params);
```

It does what is expected. However, when I change `$values` to my large array I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"0\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"1\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"2\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"3\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"4\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"5\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"6\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"7\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"8\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"9\" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. in /home/zenkohealth/public_html/tools/FBAPIExtractor/_/composerPackages/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php on line 128
```

For the large array, I did make sure to change the selected range. I added 78 columns. I then changed the range to: `Sheet1!A1:BZ1`

I would then like to add new data to my large array. Then have it import into my Google Sheet. With everything working as expected. I would add data like this:

```
$largeArray[2] = ["Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data"]
$largeArray[3] = ["Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data"]
$largeArray[4] = ["Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data","Data"]
```

But, first I can't even get 1 row to work. I think I'm missing something or have a blind spot. I would appreciate any help!

---

### Update

After taking a closer look at the error message. I see it's a JSON parsing issue.  So I think showing how I make the array is important.

```
$FBDataRow = [];

// Loop through data
for($x = 0; $x < count($response["data"]); $x++) {

$FBDataRow[$x] = [

    "$businessManagerName", // Start from 0
    $response["data"][$x]["account_name"],
    $response["data"][$x]["campaign_name"],
    $response["data"][$x]["adset_name"],
    $response["data"][$x]["ad_name"],
    "", // Delivery status
    $response["data"][$x]["objective"],
    $response["data"][$x]["impressions"],
    $response["data"][$x]["reach"],
    "", // Budget
    "", // Bid type
    $response["data"][$x]["age"],
    $response["data"][$x]["gender"],
    $response["data"][$x]["country"],
    $response["data"][$x]["region"],
    $response["data"][$x]["publisher_platform"],
    $response["data"][$x]["platform_position"],
    $response["data"][$x]["impression_device"],
    $response["data"][$x]["hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone"],
    $response["data"][$x]["spend"],
    "", // 20 - action_values.add_to_cart
    "", // 21 action_values.initiate_checkout
    "", // 22 - action_values.purchase
    "", // 23 - estimated_profit
    $response["data"][$x]["website_purchase_roas"][0]["value"],
    $response["data"][$x]["cpm"],
    $response["data"][$x]["ctr"],
    $response["data"][$x]["cpc"],
    $response["data"][$x]["website_ctr"][0]["value"],
    $response["data"][$x]["cost_per_inline_link_click"],
    "", // 30 - cost_per_action_type.landing_page_view
    "", // 31 - cost_per_action_type.view_content:
        "", // 32 - cost_per_action_type.add_to_cart
    "", // 33 - cost_per_action_type.initiate_checkout
    "", // 34 - cost_per_action_type.purchase
    "", // 35 - actions.video_view
    $response["data"][$x]["video_p25_watched_actions"][0]["value"],
    $response["data"][$x]["video_p50_watched_actions"][0]["value"],
    $response["data"][$x]["video_p75_watched_actions"][0]["value"],
    $response["data"][$x]["video_p95_watched_actions"][0]["value"],
    $response["data"][$x]["video_p100_watched_actions"][0]["value"],
    $response["data"][$x]["video_avg_time_watched_actions"][0]["value"],
    "", // 42 - actions.link_clicks
    "", // 43 - actions.landing_page_view
    "", // 44 - actions.view_content
    "", // 45 - actions.add_to_cart
    "", // 46 - actions.initiate_checkout
    "", // 47 - actions.purchase
    $response["data"][$x]["conversion_rate_ranking"],
    $response["data"][$x]["engagement_rate_ranking"],
    $response["data"][$x]["quality_ranking"],
    $response["data"][$x]["qualifying_question_qualify_answer_rate"],
    $response["data"][$x]["frequency"],
    $response["data"][$x]["unique_ctr"],
    $response["data"][$x]["cost_per_unique_click"],
    $response["data"][$x]["unique_link_clicks_ctr"],
    "", // 56 - unique_actions.link_click
    "", // 57 - cost_per_unique_action_type.landing_page_view
    "", // 58 - cost_per_unique_action_type.view_content:
    "", // 59 - cost_per_unique_action_type.add_to_cart
    "", // 60 - cost_per_unique_action_type.checkout
    "", // 61 - cost_per_unique_action_type.purchase
    "", // 62 - unique_actions.landing_page_view
    "", // 63 - unique_actions.view_content
    "", // 64 - unique_actions.add_to_cart
    "", // 65 - unique_actions.checkout
    "", // 66 - unique_actions.purchase
    "", // 67 - actions.post_engagement
    "", // 68 - actions.page_engagement
    "", // 69 - actions.post_reaction
    "", // 70 - actions.post_comment
    "", // 71 - actions.onsite_conversion.post_save
    "$businessManagerID", 
    $response["data"][$x]["account_id"],
    $response["data"][$x]["campaign_id"],
    $response["data"][$x]["adset_id"],
    $response["data"][$x]["ad_id"],
    $response["data"][$x]["date_start"],
    $response["data"][$x]["date_stop"]

];
```

Comment: Not something I've used, but have you tried just using a single cell for the range `"Sheet1!A1"` as this (according to the docs) should automatically take as much data as given.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the comment :) I've just tried that there. Still get the same error. The error is an "Invalid JSON payload received." So I don't think it has to do with the range I provide.

Comment: In order to replicate your situation, can you provide a sample value of `$response` or `$values` which occurs your error? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi there, a copy of the $values array is already at the top of the question :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed your replying. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the value of `json_encode($values)`?

Comment: You were in the right direction. I did that myself and noticed many values were null. I did type up an answer to my question around 30 mins ago. However, forgot to post it. I have just posted it now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it! :)

I decided to JSON encode the array I use with Google Sheets.

I **found that many values were marked as null**. This was not seen via the typical `print_r`

```
0       [79]
0   :   BIZ ID
1   :   B1 - A3 - Butt Seat Cushion
2   :   BSC - Test 1 - Interests - Testing - Top 5, EU - WC
3   :   Test 1 - Old age (24M) - Top 5, EU - [£19.54 / 1.593 BEP] - WC – Copy
4   :   Video 2 - Thumbnail 1
5   :   
6   :   CONVERSIONS
7   :   2689
8   :   1960
9   :   
10  :   
11  :   null
12  :   null
13  :   null
14  :   null
15  :   null
16  :   null
17  :   null
18  :   null
19  :   23.64
20  :   157.59
21  :   472.53
22  :   92.87
23  :   36.7255
24  :   3.928511
25  :   8.791372
26  :   3.049461
27  :   0.288293
28  :   2.119747
29  :   0.414737
30  :   0.4925
31  :   0.347647
32  :   3.94
33  :   2.149091
34  :   7.88
35  :   923
36  :   446
37  :   225
38  :   117
39  :   87
40  :   78
41  :   5
42  :   
43  :   48
44  :   68
45  :   6
46  :   11
47  :   
48  :   ABOVE_AVERAGE
49  :   BELOW_AVERAGE_20
50  :   AVERAGE
51  :   null
52  :   1.371939
53  :   3.214286
54  :   0.375238
55  :   2.44898
56  :   48
57  :   0.591
58  :   0.606154
59  :   4.728
60  :   4.728
61  :   7.88
62  :   40
63  :   39
64  :   5
65  :   5
66  :   3
67  :   993
68  :   993
69  :   6
70  :   
71  :   4
72  :   NAME
73  :   307978786963089
74  :   23845484873330137
75  :   23845818516690137
76  :   23845818516750137
77  :   2020-10-16
78  :   2020-11-14
```

So I decided to run a loop after making the array to replace all `null` with `""`

```
        // Remove all the "null" values from rows
        foreach ($FBDataRow as $key => $value) {

            foreach($FBDataRow[$key] as $key2 => $value2) {

                if(is_null($value2))
                    $FBDataRow[$key][$key2] = "";
            }

        }
```

This seemed to do the trick. The data imports perfectly :)